# ngx-bootstrap "en" locale missing

Tags: angular, datepicker, locale, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap for work and I need the locale part of the datepicker.
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#locales
I checked at the above website and I saw this :

[On this picture i can see "en" locale which shows an english datepicker starting on sunday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kSCo.png)

Problem : I only have "enGb" locale available in my app.module.ts

[Here "en" locale causes an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLOFL.png)

What are the solutions so i can either start "enGb" datepicker on sunday or get that "en" locale which already starts by itself on sunday.

Thanks in advance for attention.

( I use @2.0.5 ngx-bootstrap version )

Answer (score 1):

During an upgrade of my angular project, I adjusted the following for ngx-bootstrap (version: 2.0.5):

```
// OLD CODE: import { defineLocale }      from 'ngx-bootstrap/bs-moment';
import { defineLocale }                   from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';

// OLD CODE: import { nl, es, enGb }      from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
import { nlLocale, esLocale, enGbLocale}  from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';

setLocale(lang: string) {
    // Default locale corresponds with lang
    let locale = lang;
    switch (lang) {
      case 'nl': {
        // OLD CODE:  defineLocale('nl', nl);
        defineLocale('nl', nlLocale);
        break;
      }
...
}
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to change:

```
defineLocale('en', enLocale); // throws error because enLocale doesn't exist
```

to:

```
defineLocale('en'); // works, week is starting on sunday
```

According to their source files 'en' is the default language that is used when no config parameter is used. I haven't found any documentation on this, so I hope this will be useful for other people that face this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Found possible solution, from their source files, it appears as though you have to import the locales, not from the locale folder, but from the `ngx-bootstrap/chronos` folder

This is one of the many reason I try to stay away from ngx-bootstrap, they have a lot of bugs, and a lot of open tickets that they never address. They had an issue with dropdowns not actually working, like at all for a good part of 6months, not sure if they ever fixed it. I use https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home as an alternative.

Also, check this file, on their github: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/locale.ts
You will notice that enLocale is no where to be found there either. So, this looks to be yet another bug from valorsoft.

I've not used their library called chronos, but you could attempt to import directly from the chronos library, if you install that to your project.(quick google search returns nothing in terms of chronos library.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on an alternative that seems quite good.
I will think about it if i don't have any good other solutions.
I am using this for professional needs and i don't want to cause regressions.

Comment: Yea, I kept trying to use ngx so many times, but time and time again I always find a bug with at least one of their components. I was just looking through the demo. It looks like you need to import locales from

    ngx-bootstrap/chronos

instead of locale, weirdly enough.
src: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/demo/src/app/components/%2Bdatepicker/datepicker-section.list.ts